# How to use html import statements in IE11 with IE10 rendering mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have IE11 but rendering with IE10 mode. Is it possible to include html files as described here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

I tried in chrome and it works there.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/mozilla-and-web-components/